# gallery content skips fast when I click the prev and next button. why?

Tags: javascript

I took this gallery from w3school and modified it. the issue i am facing is when i click the next or prev button the items skips fast. when nothing is click it behaves normal. how do i stop it from jumping and for it to behave normal. here is the code

```
 [style]

.mySlides {display: none;}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  background:#000
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display:none
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.prev, .next{
cursor:pointer;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

#num{
background:red;
}
```

[html]

```
<h2>Automatic Slideshow</h2>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
 <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
 <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
 <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
 <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
 <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
 </div>
  <div id="num">num</div>
  </div>
  <br>
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
```

[javascript]

```
let slideIndex = 0;
showSlides(slideIndex);
document.getElementsByClassName("num").innerText = "s";


  //showSlides();
  function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
 }
 function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
 let numval =   document.getElementById("num");

if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = 1}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";  
}
 slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    

  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  

  setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
}
```

how do i stop it from jumping and for it to behave normal

Comment: One thing about editing scripts and learning is also learning how to debug your own code by reversing your edits until the problem stops. I would start be removing your own edits until the problem stops. Then you know the last change you made was the problem. Then you can problem solve that change to see why it was causing the issue.

Comment: understood and i did that multiple times. i can get the slide to change automatic and if clicked. the problem i cant seem to get pass is when i click the next button it speeds up the sliding.

Comment: so you reversed the entire thing to go back to the original? I ask this because I found the original in google and this ** setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);** isn't in the original. And that is most likely problem. Since you aren't passing anything to showSlides, n is undefined and could be causing weird issues.

Comment: here is the link to the original.  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_auto   i change the time from 2 secs to 5 secs and added prev and next buttons.